# Django routing to database based on model table

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

I have a Django (1.6) project with two databases. I have one app with one model, and multiple tables.

I want to use the database routers to set specific tables in the model to a specific database. All the documentation I have found seems to explain how to route a particular app to a particular database.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you could use a custom router and model attribute for this.

YMMV: Haven't tested this.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    _DATABASE = "foo"

class CustomRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
      database = getattr(model, "_DATABASE", None)
      return database
    # repeat for db_for_write, etc.
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @AKX. Is "_DATABASE" referring to the name of the table? So if I made all the table names name_DATABASE (where database is the name of my other database), it would detect it that way? 

Do you know if I can just reference the table names in the routers?

Comment: The value of `_DATABASE` would just refer to the database name declared in the `DATABASES` setting entry. You can figure out the table name from `model._meta.db_table`.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work in Django 1.11. I added a model attribute DATABASE_NAME to my model but it doesn't exist as far as my custom database router is concerned.